# How do you get around the need for a PartitionKey in the request options when using ReadDocumentAsync in a C# Azure Cosmos DB Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I need to access one of the items stored in a Cosmos Database, but I do not have the value of the partition key that the ReadDocumentAsync now requires.  I was using the outdated CreateDocumentQuery, but that was taking too much time to return a response to the client requesting that query.

The project is as follows, I am trying to store animals and associated enclosures in a database that have the following parameters stored in them:

```
{
    "nextId": "1",
    "id": "2",
    "predEnclosure": "true",
    "maxCapacity": 10,
    "currentCapacity": 0,
    "animals": [],
}
```

I have the partition key as the predEnclosure and would only theoretically have the id to access the enclosure off of.  I'm not sure if another method exists to retrieve documents out of the container.  This is a .NET Core Web API connecting to a Cosmos Database.

```
public async Task<CustomHttpResponseMessage<dynamic>> GetEnclosure(string id)
{
    try
    {
        Enclosure enclosure = await dbClient.ReadDocumentAsync<Enclosure>(
                dbHandler.GetDocumentUri(id), options);
        return new CustomHttpResponseMessage<dynamic>(HttpStatusCode.OK, enclosure);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Could not get given animal! Error: {e.Message}");
        return new CustomHttpResponseMessage<dynamic>(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Could not find the given enclosure!");
    }
}
```

The above will result in saying that I need a partition key to make that method call.  I expected it to return the enclosure from the database without using the partition key.

Answer (score 0):

It's bit tricky, but still you can do that,

```
MyItem item = (dynamic)client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DbName, CollectionName, id), new RequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value)}).Result.Resource;
```

Read the following ,

https://www.lytzen.name/2016/12/06/find-docs-with-no-partitionkey-in-azure.html